# Is there any way to transmit data from C++ to Flex/Air faster than sockets?

Tags: c++, apache-flex, sockets, air

I have a C++ application which sends images to a Flex/Air front-end via TCP sockets. All this data transfer occur in the same host, so the socket connects to a localhost server.

The problem is that the Flex/Air takes a really long time to read the entire image from the socket. The server sends the image quite fast, but the Flex/Air reads this image in tiny parts. The whole image has about 300MB and the Flex/AIR reads only about 1KB each iteration. So the flex keeps calling the socket data callback, which is causing the application to slowdown.

Is there any synchronous sockets to use with flex, or some kind of socket which can read the entire data all at once? If sockets aren't the best choice, is there any other faster options?

My socket class looks like this:

```
public class ClientSocket extends Socket
{

    public function ClientSocket(host:String, port:int)
    {
        super();
        addListeners();
        ...
        this.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
    }

    private function addListeners():void
    {
        ...
        addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onSocketData);
        ...
    }

    private function onSocketData(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        try
        {
            ...
            var serverMessage:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
            readBytes(serverMessage);
            ...
        }
        catch(error:Error)
        {
            //Error handling
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: As3 doesn't have synchronous socket. Could you show your data receiving source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your solution if possible. You need a http server to host your images, and send the images' filename(or url) to Flex front-end, then you can load them by URLLoader and only listen on "complete" event.

I'm sure this will be faster ;o) Is this solution appliable?

Comment: I'm not sure I can do this, because the server doesn't get the image ready to send, it makes a lot of transformation on these images. So I'd have to these transformed images, which could lead to a disk usage issue. Anyway, I'll try this solution and see how much faster it is.

Comment: I tried that out and it wasn't any faster than the socket solution. I saved the images on Apache's htdocs folder and accessed them on Air via http.

Comment: This answer itself wasn't very helpful, but I used some other things, like converting my images to bmp on server side and using canvas to draw them, and my application is much faster now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Native Extensions for AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html).  This provides an interface so that you can send data directly between C++ and AS3.  It will definitely be faster, but you need to target AIR 3.0, and you need to create an extension for each platform your code is running on.